# How to pass a nested list from python to the corresponding c++ function that takes a boost python list?

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I have a c++ boost function that is exposed to a python interrupter.
The c++ function is

```
int my_cpp_func(boost::python::list &arg){ return 0;}
```

When i pass a flat list to the c++ function from python

```
my_cpp_func(["1","2"])
```

it works fine, however, when i try to pass a nested list to the c++ function

```
my_cpp_func(["0",["1","2"]])
```

It gives the following error

> TypeError: No registered converter was able to produce a C++ rvalue
> of type std::string from this Python object of type list

So my question is how to pass a nested list from python to a boost-enabled c++ function?

Comment: I do not know boost but given the error message I assume the lists are required to be homogeneous. In general, heterogeneous lists should be avoided. What exactly is your use-case?

Comment: What's `/*some logic*/`? Provide a proper [mcve].

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Incorrect, it's just a light wrapper over the python list object that makes no assumptions about its contents. The problem is in the code OP omitted (fairly typical issue here), which likely does a bunch of `extract`s (which is when a conversion would happen) and expects the list to be flat and only contain strings.

Comment: my code is just a return; at his point. i removed all of the logic to eliminate any variables.

Comment: In that case I cannot reproduce this problem -- I can even run `my_cpp_func(["0",["1","2"], 0])` without any issues.